# Determine X/Y coordinates of cursor within a Tabulator cell

Tags: tabulator

Is there a way to accurately determine the x,y coordinates of the cursor within the viewable area of the tabulator? I've wired up a third party context-menu control to display when the user right click's on a given cell in a row. I'm using the property e.currentTarget.offsetLeft on the cell right-click event which appears to (more or less) place the menu on screen where I want it relative to the left side of the tabulator. It's the vertical/Y positioning that I'm struggling with because as soon as I scroll down several pages of tabulator data the menu vanishes. I thought that using e.currentTarget.offsetParent.offsetTop would solve this issue, but it doesn't. I'm using Tabulator v3.5. Can anyone help?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to version 4.6 it comes with built in [Context Menus](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/menu)

```js
//define row context menu
var cellContextMenu = [
    {
        label:"Reset Value",
        action:function(e, cell){
            cell.setValue("");
        }
    },
]

//add header menu in column definition
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200, contextMenu:cellContextMenu}, //add a context menu to the cells in this column
    ]
});
```

If you are concerned about jQuery and version4.x there is a [jQuery Wrapper](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/jquery) that makes the transition easy. There is also a detailed [Upgrade Guide}, most sites take a matter of minutes to a couple of hours to upgrade depending on complexity

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply Oli. Unfortunately our project timescales are tight and don't allow us the luxury to upgrade to the latest version of Tabulator at this time (and the regression testing that would be involved) so I was hoping that I could find a solution with  v3.5.

Comment: I think I've found a solution to my problem now but thanks for the heads up Oli. I'm sure we'll upgrade to the latest version of Tabulator when we're not constrained by delivery dates! Cheers.